# is NReco thread safe ? Are there any workaround ? in c#

Tags: c#, html, pdf, nreco

I am testing nReco with threadpool , i want to know is it thread safe or not , is there any other workaround ??

```
[http://www.nrecosite.com/pdf_generator_net.aspx][1]
```

1. Details Of nReco pdf generator :   free version : v2.0.50727

Answer (score 0):

PdfGenerator can be used simultaneously from different threads, but every thread should have its own instance of HtmlToPdfConverter class.

By the way, latest version of NReco.PdfGenerator is 1.1.12 (1.1.14 for LT build). You might have confused the PdfGenerator with another components that also have "NReco" namespace.

Comment: sorry my mistake , nReco version is 1.1.12, can you edit version number above in question i dont have reputation so unable to update it

Comment: Appreciate your response,  we are using ThreadPool to process multiple PDFs in parallel and as you mentioned each of the object added to the Pool creates new instance of HTMLToPdfConverter class, but for some reason it fails to process in parallel. Do you think this is because we are using a Free-license version? Would we be able to achieve this if we go with a license version of NReco? Thanks

Comment: @yashfale free version is a fully functional. I think it fails because of code that uses PdfGenerator; its hard to suggest anything without exception details, code snippet and/or HTML template samples.